# Use transactions for select statements?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I don't use Stored procedures very often and was wondering if it made sense to wrap my select queries in a transaction.

My procedure has three simple select queries, two of which use the returned value of the first.

Comment: the first statement might not need to be in the transaction

Answer (score 76, accepted):

In a highly concurrent application it could (theoretically) happen that data you've read in the first select is modified before the other selects are executed.

If that is a situation that could occur in your application you should use a transaction to wrap your selects. Make sure you pick the correct [isolation level](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173763.aspx) though, not all transaction types guarantee consistent reads.

**Update** : 
You may also find [this article](http://michaeljswart.com/2011/09/mythbusting-concurrent-updateinsert-solutions/) on concurrent update/insert solutions (aka upsert) interesting. It puts several common methods of upsert to the test to see what method actually *guarantees* data is not modified between a select and the next statement. The results are, well, shocking I'd say.

Comment: I used service broker for a high concurrent service with a similar case and had sql deadlock problem under high volume.
Applying this suggestion and **especially** the referred [article](http://michaeljswart.com/2011/09/mythbusting-concurrent-updateinsert-solutions/) above fixed all the deadlocks - thanks :-)

Answer (score 26):

**Transactions** are usually used when you have `CREATE`, `UPDATE` or `DELETE` statements and you want to have the **atomic behavior**, that is, *Either commit everything or commit nothing*.

However, you could use a transaction for `READ` select statements to:
**Make sure nobody else could update the table of interest while the bunch of your select query is executing.**

Have a look at this [msdn post](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188929.aspx).

Comment: Did you read your link?  `An application can perform actions such as acquiring locks to protect the transaction isolation level of SELECT statements`  This is a good use case for that since the OP stated they use the results of one select as parameters in subsequent queries.

Answer (score 1):

Most databases run every single query in a transaction even if not specified it is implicitly wrapped. This includes select statements.

> PostgreSQL actually treats every SQL statement as being executed within a transaction. If you do not issue a BEGIN command, then each individual statement has an implicit BEGIN and (if successful) COMMIT wrapped around it. A group of statements surrounded by BEGIN and COMMIT is sometimes called a transaction block.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/tutorial-transactions.html