# How to stop Celery creating duplicated users in this task?

Tags: python, django, celery

The code below gets run as part of a `Celery Task` to add a new user. It first checks to see if we have an existing user. Under normal circumstances this works wonderfully:

```
  def create_user(self, mobile, email=None, password=None):
        try:
            app_user = get_user_model()
            user = app_user.objects.get(mobile=mobile)
        except app_user.DoesNotExist:
            user = self.model()
            user.mobile = mobile
            user.set_password(password)
            user.save(using=self._db)

        return user
```

**My problem**: Lets say I have a file being uploaded that contains duplicated users (mobile number). The code should stop that. However, as Celery is so good, what I find is actually happening is the same two workers can sometimes run at the same time. The first `Try`statement returns nothing as they are adding the same user (mobile) then end up creating a duplicated user into the system.

i.e....

[image]

How can I stop this from happening?

My only idea is maybe at the DB level on save()? Check if the user exists, However, I always need to return a user new or existing back from this function so I run into another set of issues.

Comment: Just make the `mobile` field unique and try to create the user, capturing the exception if the user already exists - [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) rules.

Comment: @PauloScardine Thats sounds ideal, 2 things, 1) can you do that on a custom user model that extends ``BaseUserManager`` 2) does Django have a particular exception for this I can use?

Comment: You can use transactions (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/transactions/).

Comment: This question has been asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982517/use-transactions-for-select-statements

Comment: @orange forgive me maybe I don't fully understand how transactions in Django work but, I don't see how wrapping this in a transaction would help. Both worker still hit the code at the same time all we have then is a deadlock, right? But I could be wrong.

Comment: PS @orange my level is already READ COMMITTED

Comment: Did you read the 2nd link? It explains how transactions work. There shouldn't be any Django-specific way of how transactions work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since database operations are atomic, you can use [EAFP](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-eafp) (I assume the mobile field is being used as the username and so is unique):

```
try:
    return self.model.objects.create_user(
        mobile=mobile,
        password=password,
    )
except IntegrityError:
    return self.model.objects.get(mobile=mobile)
```

You may have to override the manager method `create_user` for your custom user model.

Comment: "Easier to ask for forgiveness than permission" wow thats really funny. Thanks, this works perfectly.

Comment: "The technique contrasts with the [LBYL](https://docs.python.org/2/glossary.html#term-lbyl) (look before you leap) style common to many other languages such as C."

Comment: I may apply both of these to my own life :)