# Transaction in Golang with PGX

Tags: sql, postgresql, go, transactions, postgis

I am currently in the process of creating a little Go App. Right now I am working on the DB part. The Library I use is this one: https://github.com/jackc/pgx 
The problem I have is that every time I try to execute the database read, it tells me that my 'conn is busy'. I read about using a pgxpool instead of a single connection, but it still does not work. What am I doing wrong?

```
func (postgre *PostgreClient) read(query string) (pgx.Row, error) {
    client, err := postgre.client.Acquire(context.TODO())
    transaction, err := client.BeginTx(context.TODO(), pgx.TxOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    defer transaction.Rollback(context.TODO())

    rows := transaction.QueryRow(context.TODO(), query)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    err = transaction.Commit(context.TODO())
    return rows, err
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you check the `err` from `Acquire`?

Comment: The error is nil. The error itself is a connLockError, if that helps.

Comment: Then which line in the question's code is causing "conn is busy"? Also is this your only code in your little Go App that uses the db? How many goroutines use `read`? How many acquires do you have in your code. Or how many do you assume are executed at runtime? I'm asking because the problem could be caused by acquiring too many connections and not releasing them. The one acquired by `read` is seemingly not being released. Basically it looks like you're leaking connections.

Comment: The commit causes the issue. The 'QueryRow' function executes without an error. Currently this read function gets only executed once, as I am just testing.

Comment: Then the only thing I can think of is that the result wasn't scanned yet. i.e. one usually calls `row.Scan` before commit/rollback (i'm not sure whether that's required or not though). Also your code invokes Rollback regardless of whether the query failed or not, that's not good form.

Comment: Also, given that your function is called `read` i assume the query is a plain `SELECT`? If that's the case what's the transaction for?

Comment: The issue was really that I did nothing with the row/did not close it. What I do not get is how I am supposed to handle reads now? I do not want to copy+paste this code to every single func that uses a different struct as the the Scan fuction needs a reference to a variable. Is there a way to make that more dynamic?

Comment: I use a transaction for safe reads.

Comment: Pass in an interface type that knows how to scan itself from a given row. Or, besides returning the row, return also the transaction and have the caller rollback/commit it based on how the scan went. Just the first two options off the top of my head.

Comment: What is a safe read? Are you certain it's something you need? For alternative viewpoints see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5982517/use-transactions-for-select-statements).

Comment: What do you mean by an interface type that knows how to scan itself?

Comment: Something like this: https://play.golang.org/p/BpO2bCepTGn

Comment: Awsome, thank you!
I would love to use your answer as a solution. Do you mind adding it as an offical answer?

Comment: Sorry for a side question but why did you name it "postgre"? it's "postgres", "PostgreSQL", "psql"... but certainly not "postgre"

Comment: Well, as its "real" name is "PostgreSQL" I simply cut the "SQL" part.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You have to scan the row before you commit the transaction.

If you want the handling of the transaction to remain within the function you can pass an interface that does the scanning also inside the function.

For example:

```golang
// implemented by *sql.Row & *sql.Rows
type Row interface {
    Scan(dst ...interface{}) error
}

// implemented by your "models"
type RowScanner interface {
    ScanRow(r Row) error
}
```

```golang
type User struct {
    Id    int
    Email string
}

func (u *User) ScanRow(r Row) error {
    return r.Scan(
        &u.Id,
        &u.Email,
    )
}
```

```golang
func (postgre *PostgreClient) read(query string, rs RowScanner) (err error) {
    conn, err := postgre.client.Acquire(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer conn.Release()
    
    tx, err := conn.BeginTx(context.TODO(), pgx.TxOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer func() {
        if err != nil {
            tx.Rollback(context.TODO())
        } else {
            tx.Commit(context.TODO())
        }
    }()

    row := tx.QueryRow(context.TODO(), query)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    return rs.ScanRow(row) 
}
```

```golang
u := new(User)
if err := pg.read("select id, email from users limit 1", u); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```

For scanning a list of models:

```golang
type UserList []*User

func (ul *UserList) ScanRow(r Row) error {
    u := new(User)
    if err := u.ScanRow(r); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    *ul = append(*ul, u)
    return nil
}
```

```golang
func (postgre *PostgreClient) list(query string, rs RowScanner) (err error) {
    conn, err := postgre.client.Acquire(context.TODO())
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer conn.Release()
    
    tx, err := conn.BeginTx(context.TODO(), pgx.TxOptions{})
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer func() {
        if err != nil {
            tx.Rollback(context.TODO())
        } else {
            tx.Commit(context.TODO())
        }
    }()

    rows, err := tx.Query(context.TODO(), query)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer rows.Close()
    
    for rows.Next() {
        if err := rs.ScanRow(rows); err != nil {
            return err
        }
    }
    return rows.Err()
}
```

```golang
ul := new(UserList)
if err := pg.list("select id, email from users", ul); err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
```